# how can i write in particular location of a text file in java

Tags: java, text-files

The Problem is that i have four different array lists . And  I want to insert the data of particular array list class depending on  the input given by user.
How can i do that ??

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.*;

public class acquaintances
{ 
    public static void main(String args[])
   {
     Arraylist<relative>re=new Arraylisrt<relative>();
     Arraylist<personalfriend> pf=new Arraylist<personalfriend>();
     Arraylist<casualfriend> cf=new Arraylist<casualfriend>();
     Arraylist<professionalfriend> prf=new Arraylist<professionalfriend>():
```

These are different arraylists .

Iwant to write different acquantances info in the order in the text file

casual friend 1

casual friend2

........

relative 1

relative 2

......

personalfriend1

personal friend2

personal friend3

...........

professionalfriend1

professionalfriend2

..................

Also if i delete particular detail . then how am i supposed to erase particular

detail from the file

```
     String name=null,number=null,email=null;
     File file = new File("Readme.txt");
     if (!file.exists()) {
            file.createNewFile();
        }

     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);

     int ch=0,chu=0;
     String jaff=null,baff=null;
     FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
     BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

     String cmet_why=null,cinfo=null,cdate=null;

     while(1)
     {
         System.out.println("Enter name,number,email of acquaintance");
         name=sc.nextLine();
         number=sc.nextLine();
         email=sc.nextLine();
         System.out.println("1.Create 2.Delete 3.Display 4. DisplayAll 5.Search );
        ch=sc.nextInt();
        jaff=sc.nextLine();
        Switch(ch):
        {
            case 1:
            {
                System.out.println("1.Casual friend 2.relative 3.personal friend 4. Professional friend");
                chu=sc.nextInt();
                baff=sc.nextLine();
                if(chu==1)
                {
                   System.out.println("Enter reasonto meet ,dateof meeting,info");
                   cmet_why=sc.nextLine();
                   cdate=sc.nextLine();
                   cinfo=sc.nextLine();
                   casualfriend cfriend=new casualfriend(name,number,email,cmet_why,cdate,cinfo);
```

here i added the class object to the casual friend list

and i want to write it to text file in the location.

the problem is that it is in the middle of the text file.

After this i have to write relatives,personal friends ,professional friends .

info line by line

```
                   cf.add(cfriend);

                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

}

there are different switch cases. i want to write these in the order.

Comment: Delete the file and rewrite from scratch with the updated info in whatever order you like?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What exactly do you need? Note that you cannot simply insert or remove text from random locations in a file. You'll have to write the new data to another file and then rename it.

Comment: thank you .i understood it.

Comment: If you want to insert/delete in an existing file, one way is to use `java.io.RandomAccessFile`. Note that insertions and deletions require you to move the remaining data in the file. The method` `RandomAccessFile.seek()` and `RandomAccessFile.getFilePointer()` are useful.

Comment: @5gon12eder - Your claim that you must write data to another file to insert/remove is not true.

Comment: @AndyThomas I know about memory mapped files and yes, if you move around the bytes that follow your update position you can even insert and remove text, not only overwrite it with text of the same length. I've chosen the word “simply” with care. There are few things that are truly impossible but I don't think that this is the appropriate solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void writeWithRandmoAccessFile( String content, String filePath) {

        try (RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(new File(filePath), "rw")) {

        // move the cursor to the end of the file
        // you can move the cursor to any position inside the file or to write at random positions
        randomAccessFile.seek(randomAccessFile.length());//random position

        randomAccessFile.write(content.getBytes());

        // alternatively you can use randomAccessFile.writeChars(content)
        // or randomAccessFile.writeUTF(content);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```